# Change of variables in a system of differential equations

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, change-of-variable

Given the following system :

$x'' + ax' + cx = kf(t) + cy$

$y'' + by' + cy = hf(t) + cx$

where $a,b,c,k,h$ are costants. It seems straightforward to set $z = x + y$ in order to get an equation like $z'' + s z' = (k+h)f(t) $. Now the problem is that I cannot find a value for the parameter $s$ and I don't even know if it is actually possible to find such $s$. Could you kindly help me please? Many thanks

Comment: I have a system made of two masses linked with a damping and I need to control the system, from the standard equations of motion ,via an other change of coordinates, I've got the system in the question and now I would like to find $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ but it is not easy, I've also tried with Laplace but I've got  nowhere near a solution. Hence, I thought of bringing everything in one dimension.

Comment: $f(t)$ is a generic input function, the parameters are all greater than zero. The problem with a first order system is the computation of the eigenvalues and no, I can't use numerical methods.